# The width option of sscanf does not work

Tags: c, scanf

I wanted to use the width option (http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) of sscanf to control the maximal bytes to read. But the following reads more than 3 bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  long long ll;
  char str[4];
  int pos;  
  sscanf(" 281", "%3llx%n", &ll, &pos);
  printf("%llx %d\n", ll, pos);
  sscanf(" 281", "%3s%n", &str, &pos);
  printf("%s %d\n", str, pos);
  return 0;
}
```

It prints out the following.

```
281 4
281 4
```

I had thought it prints

```
28 3
28 3
```

Is this the correct use of sscanf? fscanf works in the similar way.

Comment: Width refers to a **single field**.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I do not know if it can work as I expected. My goal is to read the next 3 bytes in terms of some format. Does sscanf always ignore the space and count the 3 bytes after the space?

Comment: No, width does not apply to the whole format string but to a single specific field (you may specify multiple widths in different fields). You _may_ read strings (to parse later) if you want the raw number of bytes

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Is a field in sscanf separated by space?

Comment: Perhaps `%3[ 0-9]` will be what you want.

Comment: @JoeC What is the goal? "control the maximal bytes to read" 3 in this case or "read the next 3 bytes".  Is 3 the max or should code always read 3?

Comment: @chux the goal is reading always the next 3 bytes (including spaces). After reading the 3 bytes, we convert them into a value based on sscanf format, for example %d, %llx, ... After reading all the comments, I decided using fread 3 bytes to a buffer, and then using sscanf to parse the buffer.

Comment: Consider `char s[4];
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(" 281", "%3c%n", s, &n);
  s[n] = 0;
  printf("<%s>\n", s);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some (most) formats implicitly skip whitespace (basically everything except `%c` and `%[`). Skipped whitespace does not count towards the maximum field width.

Comment: "(everything except %c, %[ and %n)"  see also C11 §7.21.6.2 8